Unable to connect Eureka Client to Server
I am trying to connect a GatewayApplication to a Eureka Server.
The following is the application.yml for the Eureka Client. I am running it on Development Profile and have verified the same.
spring:
  application:
    name: GatewayApplication
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: Development

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    hostname: localhost
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: Production

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_HOST:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    hostname: localhost

This is the output is am getting on the console for the client application:
2024-12-21T13:31:57.367+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Unable to set redirect follow using reflection
2024-12-21T13:31:57.374+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAYAPPLICATION/fedora:GatewayApplication:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:76)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1046)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:961)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:410)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:245)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:240)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:324)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.lambda$instantiate$0(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiateWithFactoryMethod(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:375)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:727)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:83)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:323)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:510)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at com.PokerAI.GatewayApplication.GatewayApplication.main(GatewayApplication.java:11)

2024-12-21T13:31:57.374+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initial registry fetch from primary servers failed
2024-12-21T13:31:57.374+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
2024-12-21T13:31:57.375+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initial registry fetch from backup servers failed
2024-12-21T13:31:57.376+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2024-12-21T13:31:57.380+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2024-12-21T13:31:57.385+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1734768117382 with initial instances count: 0
2024-12-21T13:31:57.393+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application GATEWAYAPPLICATION with eureka with status UP
2024-12-21T13:31:57.395+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1734768117395, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2024-12-21T13:31:57.398+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAYAPPLICATION/fedora:GatewayApplication:8080: registering service...
2024-12-21T13:31:57.404+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Unable to set redirect follow using reflection
2024-12-21T13:31:57.405+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAYAPPLICATION/fedora:GatewayApplication:8080 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:76) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:828) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:125) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$2.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:105) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-12-21T13:31:57.415+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:76) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:828) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:125) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$2.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:105) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-12-21T13:31:57.435+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-12-21T13:31:57.439+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8080
2024-12-21T13:31:57.482+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [           main] c.P.G.GatewayApplication                 : Started GatewayApplication in 6.574 seconds (process running for 8.116)
2024-12-21T13:32:12.491+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [ionShutdownHook] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application GATEWAYAPPLICATION with eureka with status DOWN
2024-12-21T13:32:12.492+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [ionShutdownHook] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1734768132492, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2024-12-21T13:32:12.493+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAYAPPLICATION/fedora:GatewayApplication:8080: registering service...
2024-12-21T13:32:12.498+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Unable to set redirect follow using reflection
2024-12-21T13:32:12.498+05:30  INFO 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
2024-12-21T13:32:12.499+05:30  WARN 4302 --- [GatewayApplication] [foReplicator-%d] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAYAPPLICATION/fedora:GatewayApplication:8080 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

This is application.yml for the server application
spring:
  application:
    name: DiscoveryService
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: Development

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

---
# TODO: Change as needed in Production
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: Production
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false


This is also active on the Development profile
Tried changing the YAML file with different properties for the eureka parent but made no changes to behaviour.

Figured out the solution. I was using spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc dependency instead of spring-cloud-starter-gateway.
